# Check ssh server exists in R

Tags: r, ssh

I work with sensor data that is stored on servers that I access using putty/SSH on a windows 7 machine. To check server status, I can manually connect to each server ip address using putty but would like to automate this process in R. I tried invoking a system command:

```
shell("nmap -p [port] [ip address]")
```

This only tells me the port is open but not weather I can connect to the host. Computer networking is fairly new to me so I'm not sure how to proceed, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution using `system` is to connect using telnet and grep for "SSH" in output. You can close session after timeout using sleep and pipe.

```
    out <- system("echo quit; sleep 1 | telnet 178.62.250.163 22", intern=T)
    length(grep("SSH", out)) != 0
```